# Store multiple json object in to a text file iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

When there is no internet connection on device, i am storing the json in to a text file. But the problem is, if i do again it is getting replaced. Here is what i am doing for store into a text file. How to store multiple json object in a text file.When i get connection i need to post json to server.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.json"];
[jsonString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not so straight forward as concatenating multiple JSON files does *not* result in a valid JSON file.  To do this properly requires you to read and parse the existing JSON file, which will give you an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` top-level object, then append the data from the new JSON file and write the whole thing out.

That is inefficient as you are processing old data.

Therefore I would suggest you write new data to a new file, using the current date/time for the filename, and when it's time to upload, read each of the files and upload them individually, one-at-a-time. Then delete each file as it's uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to append text to file

```
-(void) writeToLogFile:(NSString*)content{
content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",content];

 //get the documents directory:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.json"];

NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileName];
if (fileHandle){
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
}
else{
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:NO
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:nil];
}
```

}

Comment: And is the result valid JSON?

Comment: yes maintain some seperator while appending it  & retrieve json data using this seperator & post to ur server.